# Did they remove the make:auth command in Laravel 6.0?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-6

I wanted to create a new project so I can fiddle with the authentication a bit, see what I could do. However, when I tried to run the `make:auth` command, I got an error.

I decided to look in the composer.json file to see if I maybe had an outdated Composer version, but I saw the updated laravel/framework.

I can't find anything about the `make:auth` command being removed on so I thought I'd come here and ask about it.

```
Command "make:auth" is not defined.

  Did you mean one of these?
      make:channel
      make:command
      make:controller
      make:event
      make:exception
      make:factory
      make:job
      make:listener
      make:mail
      make:middleware
      make:migration
      make:model
      make:notification
      make:observer
      make:policy
      make:provider
      make:request
      make:resource
      make:rule
      make:seeder
      make:test
```

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#introduction) is the greatest help :)

Comment: You can install the laravel/ui package via composer:
composer require laravel/ui

The ui:auth Command
php artisan ui:auth

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First Install the laravel/ui Composer package with the following command:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

and then run the following command in a new  Laravel application:

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Laravel 6 has moved the Auth Scaffolding into a seperate package.

Source : https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/authentication

Comment: php artisan ui:auth

Answer (score 2):

Yes in Laravel 6 `auth` command has been removed and authentication scaffolding has been moved as separate package named `laravel/ui`

Here you can read about [Laravel 6](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/releases) and [laravel/ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui) and also here you can read about `laravel/ui` in laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/frontend)

Thanks